# Difference between slow and inertial manifolds?

Tags: dynamical-systems

Could anyone provide a clear definition of the basic difference between two of the invariant manifold types - the inertial and slow manifolds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Debusche and R. Temam write in their article "Inertial Manifolds and Slow Manifolds", published in Appl. Math. Lett. Vol. 4, No. 4, pp. 73-76,1991: "We show in fact that a slow manifold is a special type of inertial manifold." I think these authors have written several papers on this topic, which hopefully clarify the difference.

Comment: Thanks, that's a very helpful article - I probably should have found that myself.